# Не получается извлечь элемент с сайта

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь извлечь элемент с сайта, но не могу.
Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent



agent = UserAgent()

response = requests.get(url='https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/48937583/detail.aspx', headers={
    'user-agent': f'{agent.random}'
}).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml').find('div', class_='product-page__breadcrumbs breadcrumbs')
print(soup)
```

```
None
```

Подскажите, как извлечь его с сайта

Answer (score 1):

Контент страницы наполняется при помощи ajax средствами javascript. Вам нужно смотреть в сторону управления браузером (например selenium), а не парсинга статичных html-файлов